# Querying DBpedia for English-only description (with SPARQL)

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, sparql, dbpedia

I'm querying dbpedia.org for a description of Big Ben with this SPARQL query:

```
select ?desc 
where {
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Big_Ben> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#comment> ?desc
}
```

This returns a list of descriptions in at least 10 different languages. How do I specify that I only want the English language description?

Comment: BTW. How can we find Big Ben URI(one and exact)

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747019/how-get-dbpedia-data-in-a-specific-language

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The keys you need to know are that str() and lang() pull apart the text and language of the value, so you can do this:

```
select str(?desc) 
where {
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Big_Ben> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#comment> ?desc
  FILTER (langMatches(lang(?desc),"en"))
}
```