# How get DBpedia data in a specific language?

Tags: web-services, semantics, sparql, ontology, dbpedia

i tried this request
http://lookup.dbpedia.org/api/search.asmx/KeywordSearch?QueryClass=film&QueryString=transformers&MaxHits=1

but if i want to retrieve info in italian language?

it there another service (similar this) that can?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use [dbpedia SPARQL endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql) to run query. For example:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
SELECT ?film ?description ?film_name WHERE {
    ?film rdf:type <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Film>.
    ?film foaf:name ?film_name.
    ?film rdfs:comment ?description .
    FILTER (LANG(?description)='it' && ?film_name="Transformers"@en)
}
```