# How to get DBpedia 3.8 data in a specific language that is not among 12 most popular languages?

Tags: web-services, sparql, semantics, dbpedia

In my case, language is Ukrainian. It is easy to find data in German or French (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747019/how-get-dbpedia-data-in-a-specific-language)), but what about other not so popular languages? I can't manage to find any data in Ukrainian (uk), even though now it's actually the 16th biggest wikipedia section. The DBpedia wiki states that it has data in all of the wikipedia languages, but how do I get that data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are talking about accessing DBPedia online via http://dbpedia.org/sparql?

Note that not all the data produced by the DBPedia project is available through the SPARQL endpoint, the documentation on their [Datasets Loaded](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/DatasetsLoaded39) page covers what is loaded and does not appear to have any Ukranian data present.

However the project does provide many datasets in many other languages, you just need to download them yourself and load them into the triple store of your choice.  For Ukranian see [Ukranian Downloads of DBPedia 3.9](http://downloads.dbpedia.org/3.9/uk/).

Note that for future reference you may prefer to start at the root of their [downloads site](http://downloads.dbpedia.org) so you ensure you always download the latest versions of the datasets.

Comment: Thanks s lot! Now I see that it's only possible to use Ukrainian database if it's download. Pity, though.

Comment: Another question that now arises is: what should I do with the downloaded datasets? How do I use them? I assume that I need to install something like a service on my machine, but where do I get it? Can't find a simple plain explanation of how to use it on dbpedia site...

Comment: One option may be to use [Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com) which is the software used to power the public DBPedia sites, see [here](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtBulkRDFLoaderExampleDbpedia) for documentation on loading the downloaded datasets into a local Virtuoso instance

Comment: @Maksym You might also take a look at [Querying large RDF Datasets out of memory](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17005778/1281433) which talks about how to set up a Jena [Fuseki](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/serving_data/) instance using Jena's TDB.  The second half of my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16608265/1281433) has an example of how you can load data into TDB.